# Understanding of a proof about upper/lower triangular matrices property under multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

**Show that the product of two upper (lower) triangular matrices is again upper (lower) triangular.**

I have problems in formulating proofs - although I am not 100% sure if this text requires one, as it uses the verb "show" instead of "prove". However, I have found on the internet the proof below but my problem is not just that I can't do one by myself, but also that it happens that I don't understand a proof which is already written - thing which let me think that I should quit these studies.

**My first question is: how to choose the right strategy for proving something, in this case as in others?**. I guess it is also matter of interest...Interest for numbers and their properties. I've never had such interest, frankly - although, perhaps, it is not nice to say this here. The reason for which I started studying math and some physics over an year and a half ago is because I dreamed about and still dreaming to do a kind of research for which I am interested and I need scientific background.

Sorry for the digression but I am so upset and I need some general advice too. Coming back to the topic of the present proof, **my second question is: could you explain me in plain English the idea and logic behind the following proof, please? Is this proof general enough to cover also my case and what changes do I need to add for it?** - I ask this because the text to which I refer speaks about upper and lower triagular matrices, while the text of the proof I report here speaks about upper triangular matrices only. I also notice that the following proof considers only square matrices but also rectangular matrices can be upper/lower triangular.

The only thing I know about all this is what upper/lower triangular matrices are and how to perform multiplication between matrices. This is the proof found on the internet:

"Suppose that U and V are two upper triangular *n × n* matrices. By the row-column rule for matrix multiplication we know that the *(i,j)-th* entry of the product UV is $ui1v1j + ui2v2j +···+ uinvnj$. We need to show that if i > j then this expression evaluates to 0. In fact, we will show that every term $uikvkj$ of this expression evaluates to 0. To prove this, we consider two cases: • If i > k then $uik = 0$ since U is upper triangular. Hence $uikvkj = 0$. • If k > j then $vkj = 0$ since V is upper triangular. Hence $uikvkj = 0$. Since i > j, for every k weeither have $i > k$ or $k > j$ (possibly both) so the  set wo cases cover all possibilities for k."

Comment: no answers? :( ...please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this:

In $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nu_{ik}v_{kj}\enspace(i>j)$, then

- either $i>k$ and $u_{ik}=0$, hence $u_{ik}v_{kj}=0$,
- or $k\ge i>j$  and $v_{kj}=0$, hence $u_{ik}v_{kj}=0$.

In plain English, it says that in each term of the sum at least one of $u_{ik}$, $v_{kj}$ is $0$, hence the sum is $0$.

Comment: Thank you! But in my question, perhaps too long, I ask if you can explain me the proof in plain English.

Comment: I mean, I have to proof. The fact is that I can't get it. Perhaps, also cause of the formal language.

Comment: For instance, why $i$ need to be greater than $j$?

Comment: I don't understand both condition and the consequences of the proof.

Comment: We're interested in prooving that, in the product, terms *under* the diagonal are $0$. These terms are characterised by the fact their row index is greater than their column index, whence $i>j$.

Comment: But terms can be 0 also above the diagonal and we have still (lower) triangular matrices

Comment: That is true, but for lower triangular matrices, we don't care.

Comment: why don't we care?

Comment: The defining condition is about the coefficients *under* the diagonal. The other coefficients are what they are.

Comment: Can I write the proof in your way? I mean, is what you wrote complete?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31059/discussion-between-always-learning-and-bernard).

Answer (score 1):

I was interested on the same question, so allow me to exploit my logic, hopping of course to get comments for possible flaws. Suppose you have two lower triangular matrices $\mathbf{L}_1$ and $\mathbf{L}_2$ illustrated bellow

$$\mathbf{L}_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
l_{11}^{(1)} & l_{12}^{(1)}   & \dots        & \dots  & l_{1n}^{(1)} &\\
             & l_{22}^{(1)}   & l_{23}^{(1)} & \dots  & \vdots       &\\
             &                & l_{33}^{(1)} &        & \vdots       &\\
             &                &              & \ddots & \vdots       &\\
             &                &              &        & l_{nn}^{(1)} &\\
\end{bmatrix}~~~~~\mathbf{L}_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
l_{11}^{(2)} & l_{12}^{(2)}   & \dots        & \dots  & l_{1n}^{(2)} &\\
             & l_{22}^{(2)}   & l_{23}^{(2)} & \dots  & \vdots       &\\
             &                & l_{33}^{(2)} &        & \vdots       &\\
             &                &              & \ddots & \vdots       &\\
             &                &              &        & l_{nn}^{(2)} &\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

We want to prove that the following product is a lower triangular matrix,

$$\mathbf{L}_1 \mathbf{L}_2 = \mathbf{L}_1 \big[ \mathbf{l}_1, \mathbf{l}_2^{(2)}, \dots, \mathbf{l}_n^{(2)} \big] = \big[ \mathbf{L}_1 \mathbf{l}_1^{(2)}, \mathbf{L}_1 \mathbf{l}_2^{(2)}, \dots, \mathbf{L}_1 \mathbf{l}_n^{(2)} \big]$$

As we can see, the $k$-th column of product matrix $\mathbf{L}_1 \mathbf{L}_2$ is given by $\mathbf{L}_1 \mathbf{l}_k^{(2)}$ which is the linear combination of the $\mathbf{L_1}$ matrix columns with coefficients defined by the $k$-th column vecor $\mathbf{l}_k^{(2)}$. **Each of the product matrix columns $\big(\mathbf{L}_1 \mathbf{l}_k^{(2)}\big)$ have possible non-zeros entries only above the $k$-th element.**

This is because, the new columns are linear combinations of the first $k$ columns $\mathbf{l}_k^{(1)}$ which by their turn have possible non-zero values above their $k$-th entry. This property comes form the fact that columns $\mathbf{l}_k^{(2)}$ have zero entries after their $k$-th element.

$\mathcal{Thanks~for~reading}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the two upper triangular matrices be A(nxn) and B(nxn). And let C=AB.

Now, for matrix multiplication, $$C_{ij}=\sum_{r=1}^n A_{ir}B_{rj}$$

Since, A and B are upper triangular matrices,

$A_{ir}=0$ , when i>r

$B_{rj}=0$ , when r>j

So, For an element of C (i.e., $A_{ir}B_{rj}$) to be non zero, both $A_{ir}$ and $B_{rj}$
need to be non zero.

This happens when both i$\le$r and  r$\le$j.  This means i$\le$j.

So, the only non-zero elements in C are those with i$\le$j.

The previous statement is the condition required for an upper triangular matrix.

Hence it is clear that the product of two upper triangular matrices (in our case C) is always an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: thanks for this great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

$n\times n$ matrices are (or at least readily can be viewed) as linear maps from $n$-dimensional space to itself.

An upper triangular matrix is one where each vector from the standard basis is mapped to a linear combination of itself and the *preceeding* base vectors alone. In other words: The subspaces spanned by the first few basis vectors is mapped into itself (no matter how many "first few" I take).

The product of matrices corresponds to the composition of the linear maps. And of the subspace spanned by the first few basis vectors is mapped into itself by each of the factors, this also holds for their composition / the matrix product. Therefore the product is upper triangular.

Comment: In my task I have to show the same property for lower triangular matrices. see first line in bold.